# Find minimal value for product of the sums

Tags: calculus

Find minimal value for product of the sums
$$\left( x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots \right)
\left( \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2!x^2}+\frac{1}{3!x^3}+\dots \right)
$$
Here what we did about solution. We know these series equals Taylor expansion of $(e^x-1)(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$.  We tried to apply derivative test to find minimal value but it is hard to find extreme values from the equation we get.

Do you have any trick to find the minimal? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by sum of the product?

Comment: It is enough to consider $x \in [-1,1]$. As out of that interval the argument can just be reversed.

Comment: What would be the next term? $x^4/2.34$? $x^4/2.4$?

Comment: $2.3$ or $2\cdot 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Set, for $x>0$,
$$
f(x)=(e^x-1)(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)=e^{x+\frac{1}{x}}-e^x-e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1
$$ giving
$$
f'(x)=\left(1-\frac1{x^2} \right)e^{x+\frac{1}{x}}-e^x+\frac1{x^2}e^{\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{e^{\frac{1}{x}}-e^{\frac{1}{x}+x}-e^x x^2+e^{\frac{1}{x}+x} x^2}{x^2}
$$ then observe that $f'(1)=0$, $f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<1$ and  $f'(x)>0$ for $x>1$.

The minimum is thus

> $$f(1)=(e-1)^2.$$

Comment: Why dont you check $x<0$ ?

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}$ there is no minimum: $$\lim_{x\to -\infty}(e^x-1)(e^{1/x}-1) = \large 0.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, one may notice a local maximum at $x=-1$.